Raspberry Pi Camera Python OpenCV Exposure Control
I'm capturing images from a Raspberry Pi Camera Module v2 using OpenCV in Python (picamera is too slow for my purposes).
I need to increase the exposure time, and have been trying to do that using a v4l2 call to the terminal from within Python:
# Initialise camera with OpenCV
vid = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video0")
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1088)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)

# Initialise window for video image
visinit = np.zeros(shape=(1920, 1088, 3)).astype("uint8")
windowname = "Video Live View"
cv2.namedWindow(windowname, cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
cv2.imshow("Video Live View", visinit)
cv2.resizeWindow("Video Live View", 960, 540)
cv2.moveWindow("Video Live View", 910, 170)

# Set video camera exposure
exposuretime = 800
command = "v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -c auto_exposure=1 -c exposure_time_absolute=" + str(exposuretime)
output = subprocess.call(command, shell = True)

# Record indefinitely until user presses q
num = 0
while True: 
    stream_ret, vidframe = vid.read(0)
    if stream_ret:
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break;
        # Get time
        ts = time.time()
        # Set time format for filename
        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S-%f')[:-3]
        # Construct video filename
        vidfilename = "Video-7.5Hz-Cage-XX-" + str(st) + "-"
        # Flip video frame (camera is upside down)
        vidframe = cv2.rotate(vidframe, cv2.ROTATE_180)
        # Convert video frame to grayscale
        vidframe = cv2.cvtColor(vidframe, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Write video frame
        cv2.imwrite(str(vidfilename) + str(num).zfill(7) + ".jpg", vidframe, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 50])
        # Display video frame
        cv2.imshow("Video Live View", vidframe)
        num += 1
        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

However, making the v4l2 call from within Python does not set the exposure time as high as if I manually run the same command from the Terminal, after running the Python script (the resulting images are substantially brighter using the latter method).
I get exactly the same maximum exposure from within Python if I try to set it using OpenCV, replacing the v4l2 call with:
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0.75)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, exposuretime)

Is there a reason for this behaviour? And, is there a way of setting the full range of exposure time from within Python that's compatible with OpenCV? Ideally, I don't want to have to run terminal commands externally, after the Python script to achieve the exposure I need.
Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Did you try with cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, ...)? What was your actual code? What happened?

I've edited the answer to clarify the OpenCV version I tried - it only increases exposure up to the same maximum I got using the v4l2 call within Python.
